# How to correctly remove a stored procedure from DataEntities.edmx?

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

If I define a stored procedure `myStoredProcedure` using Visual Studio Server Explorer in "Stored Procedures" folder, then I go to the `.edmx` to update the model.

I can use that `myStoredProcedure` in the code behind, and can be detected by IntelliSense, and works fine.

When I remove `myStoredProcedure` from the database and from the `.edmx` model.
It is still detected by IntelliSense. Even if it has no trace neither in Server Explorer -> "Stored Procedures" folder nor in `.emdx` "Stored Procedures / Functions" folder.

When it is used no compile error shown, but runtime error (Of course expected).

> The function import 'DataEntities.myStoredProcedure' cannot be executed because it is not mapped to a store function.

If I re-define `myStoredProcedure` again in the Database -> Server Explorer -> "Stored Procedures", and update the `.edmx` model. The IntelliSense detects two:

- `myStoredProcedure`  -> this is the old one, and causes runtime error.
- `myStoredProcedure1` -> this is the new one, and works fine.

So how to correctly remove a stored procedure from `DataEntities.edmx`?

Comment: You need to remove the procedure in the Model Browser and regenerate code (if it does not happen automatically). Server explorer is not connected to the EF Designer and removing anything from there will not update your model (and vice versa).

Comment: @Pawel I already said in the question that I remove the procedure from both the database in Server explorer and from the .edmx model.

Answer (score 6):

There's three places in the Model Browser that need objects deleted to completely remove a stored procedure.
1. Stored Procedures / Functions folder
2. Function Imports folder
3. Complex Types folder

Comment: I initially edited the XML, but this GUI method is a safer way to get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on edmx--> Open with... --> XML (Text) Editor --> Find and remove all related xml blocks that refer to your procedures' name.

[Open with XML Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb7iD.png)

Make sure you find and remove everything related to it.

[Delete related xml blocks_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vZkg.png)

[Delete related xml blocks_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncnO6.png)

If your procedure comes with a suffix _Result search also for everything without it and remove all xml blocks referred to it also.

After that hit Ctrl + S to save the edmx.

Now delete the cs related file named after your procedure under the .tt of your edmx

You can validate that the procedure is no longer mapped if you now open the .edmx normally from designer, click on it and hit Ctrl+s. If it would be still mapped it would be recreated.

Answer (score -1):

I discovered the Refresh and Delete tabs on the EF Update Wizard recently.  The Add tab is what you normally see but alongside the Refresh and Delete tabs.  The Refresh tab is very quick and simple to use. ;)

Comment: Doesn't refresh StoredProcedures - hence the question